# is it an issue to have 50-100 queries run on a single public facing page?

Tags: mysql, database-design

TABLES:

thread: id, name

thread_participants: thread_id, user_id

I want to create a page to list out thread names and participants.  What I am currently doing is
running a query for the threads, then a query for each thread to get its participants.
What I am concerned about is the number of queries that may run.  For instance, if I list out 
20 threads/page, then that's 21 queries for that page for this operation. furthermore, if I want to get information for each 
user, then the number of queries can rise significantly, unless I perform a join, which may/may not
be economical to do so.

Would you consider it to be an issue to have 50-100 queries run on a single public facing page?

Would it be better to run one query for the threads, and another for the particiants using WHERE IN(...), then
sorting the users out in the application?

Comment: 50-100 queries sounds excessive. The odds are there is a more efficient way to do it. And joins aren't *that* slow. They're *a lot* faster then doing numerous of queries.

Comment: The joins would only be necessary if I wanted to append some user data. if, however, I only wanted the thread names and and participants than the solutions I came up with are the two above: (1) running 1 query for the threads, and another for the participants of each thread.  (2) getting all the users for all the threads, then sorting the users in the application.

Comment: I also felt like that 50-100 queries was excessive.  Part of the reason for my question was to see if I was being too conservative in my assumption.

Comment: Neither are the correct way @Jason; you can JOIN the tables together and pick out all the users for all the threads you're interested in.

Answer (score 0):

This would depend on a few factors such as number of visitors expected to be hitting that page, and the actual SQL query itself. You might want to consider running some performance metrics to see how long these queries are taking, whether there are opportunities for caching, and how the site changes when you put more stress on it (i.e. stress test).

Comment: In terms of expected visitors, there is no upper limit. Its a public page so it could be 1 user or it could be thousands...  The queries itself, they are straight-forward selects. I can only come up with 2 solutions and would like to know if i'm missing something

Comment: The threads itself won't be static, so any cached items will be short lived.